# Custom validation implementation for Check box rendering in table format

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, angularjs-validation

I have a requirement in which I have to display check box in a row (Tabular way of displaying). I could not use the default checkbox implementation which Ionic provides due to some issue while displaying in a single row.

Therefore I came up with a implementation [like this](http://codepen.io/shashankHS/pen/WRNmgW?editors=1000). Here I am using check mark icons from Ionicons, based on a flag I set it to true/false.

Till here its all good. But when it comes to **Validation** its not working as desired. When no checkbox is selected also **form validation returns, form as valid**.

Below is the sample HTML code

```
<form  name="form" id="form" novalidate>
  <div class="row">

<div ng-repeat="ao in counter"
     ng-class="{ 'has-errors-left' : form.cb_{{ao.id}}.$invalid && {{isRequired}} == true && $first, 
                 'has-errors-right' : form.cb_{{ao.id}}.$invalid && {{isRequired}} == true && $last,
                 'no-errors-left' : form.cb_{{ao.id}}.$valid && {{isRequired}} == true && $first,
                 'no-errors-right' : form.cb_{{ao.id}}.$valid && {{isRequired}} == true && $last }"
     id="border"                                       
     class="col col-33 item item-divider removeDividerColor parentDiv">
         <a class="button button-icon icon answerOption_{{ao.id}} answerOptionCB childDiv"
            ng-class="{ 'ion-ios-checkmark-outline': checkStatus === false, 'ion-ios-checkmark': checkStatus === true }"
            id="cb_{{ao.id}}"
            name="cb_{{ao.id}}" on-tap="checkStatus = !checkStatus"
            ng-required="!getRequired(isRequired, ao.id)"
            ng-init="checkStatus = false"
            ng-model="checkStatus">{{ao.Text}}
        </a>             
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have created a codepen in the above link. Kindly let me know where I am going wrong or is there any better way to implement group of checkbox in a tabular way (displayed in a single row).

Answer (score 0):

**You need to update your code in this way-**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ng-form name="myForm">
  <span ng-repeat="choice in choices">
    <label class="checkbox" for="{{choice.id}}">
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{choice.id}}" ng-click="updateQuestionValue(choice)" ng-model="choice.checked" name="group-one" id="{{choice.id}}" ng-required="value.length==0" />
{{choice.label}}
    </label>
  </span>
  <input type="submit" value="Send" ng-click="submitSurvey(survey)" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" />
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

And Script goes here:-

```
function myCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.choices = [{"id":1, "value":"1", "label":"Good"}, {"id":2, "value":"2","label":"Ok"},{"id":3, "value":"3","label":"Bad"}];
    $scope.value = [];
    $scope.updateQuestionValue = function(choice){
        $scope.value = $scope.value || [];
        if(choice.checked){
            $scope.value.push(choice.value);
            $scope.value = _.uniq($scope.value);
        }else{
            $scope.value = _.without($scope.value, choice.value);
        }
    };
}
```

You can see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thbkA/4/) here.